Determine the ideals of $\frac{\mathbb{Z}[x]}{\langle x^3-x\rangle}$ .Are the prime ideals same as the maximal ideals?
Now i tried the following . First i thought of the chinese remainder theorem since $x^3-x=x(x-1)(x+1)$ and i thought my ring is isomorphic to $ \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ which is wrong since the ideals $x-1, x+1$ are not coprime in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.
So there goes that.
Second try: From the correspondence theorem i have to find all ideals in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ such that they contain $\langle x^3-x \rangle$ so they must be of the form $I=\langle x,x-1,x+1,f_1,\ldots,f_m\rangle$ where $f_i$ are polynomials of degree less or equal than 2. That's where i cannot continue this one.
Third try: Actually write down $\frac{\mathbb{Z}[x]}{\langle x^3-x\rangle}$ as the ring of cosets of $\langle x^3-x\rangle$ so every element is $f(x)+\langle x^3-x\rangle$ where $\deg f(x) \leq2$. Now this ring is not a PID so again i cannot continue more in describing its ideals.
Usually there is something  in the quotient that makes it a PID at least so its easier to find the ideals but not in this one or am i missing something?..

Your ring is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z \times ( \Bbb Z[x]/(x^2-1))$, see here.

@Dietrich yeah i also figured that out dont know how ti helps tho. Cause i cannot simpliofy it tou ZxZxZ

you can use \langle and \rangle to get $\langle\cdot \rangle$

I am not sure there is an easy description of the ideals of your quotient ring.
As you pointed out, such ideals are in 1-1 correspondence with ideals   of $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ containing $x^3-x$.
Nevertheless, one can answer your second question. The ideal $(2,x^3-x)/(x^3-x)$ is prime but not maximal, as the corresponding quotient ring is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}[X]$ (also: it is strictly contained in $(2,x)/(x^3-x)$)

@GreginGre $J = (2,x^3-x)/(x^3-x)$ is not prime because $R/J = (\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{Z}[X])/(\bar X^3 - \bar X)$ which is no domain ($R = \mathbb{Z}[X]/(X^3-X)$). You mean an ideal like $I = (x,x^3-x)/(x^3-x)$? Then $R/I = \mathbb{Z}$ which is no field but a domain, so $I$ is prime but not maximal.
